# I am getting `Can not use keyword 'await' outside of a async function` within an Async function.. React-native

Tags: react-native, async-await

I am having an issue with async await for my AsyncStorage function within my React-native application. The error I'm getting is:

```
Can not use keyword 'await' outside of a async function
```

As you can see below, it's obvious that await is within the function. What am I doing wrong to get this error?

```
_retrieveData = async function (location) {
  try {
    var index = await AsyncStorage.getItem(location, (err, result) => result).then(result => result).catch(error=>console.log(error))
    if (index !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(index)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return null
  }
};

_storeData = async function(location, value) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.set(location, JSON.stringify(value));

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 arrow functions

```
const _retrieveData = async location => {
  try {
    let index = await AsyncStorage.getItem(location)
    if (index !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(index);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

const _storeData = async (location, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.set(location, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Now it's returning a promise, even if I do `.then(result=> result)` it is still returning a promise. Do you know this is supposed to be handled?

Comment: Btw it should be AsyncStorage.setItem not just set. Secondly please explain what you are trying to achieve on both functions. And also use hooks to store whatever you are trying to to store rather than using return

Answer (score 0):

Make them as an arrow functions

```
_retrieveData = async location => {
  try {
    let index = await AsyncStorage.getItem(location)
    if (index !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(index);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

_storeData = async (location, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.set(location, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```